# oracle equivalent 'IN' function in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I can't believe it's so hard to find an example in informatica documentation.

I would like to check if a string column that matches any of the following strings: 'A', 'B', 'C'

In Oracle, it would be as simple as:

```
where column in ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

I have the following in the expression component

```
iif(column in ('1','2','3'), 'apple', iif(column in ('4','5','6','7','8'), 'orange', 'Unknown'))
```

and I got syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informatica has `in()` clause.  Here is the syntax `in (data_col, 'val1','val2', [case_flag])`.
`case_flag` - This can be 0 for case insensitive comparison, and non zero/default int is case sensitive.
This returns 0 for false and 1 for True.
You can change your code like -

```
iif(in (column,'1','2','3')=1, 'apple', 
   iif(in (column , '4','5','6','7','8')=1, 'orange', 'Unknown')
)
```

This search is case sensitive and does an exact match.

Comment: thanks. I missed that =1 for the IN function.